# Javascript стринги в отдельный файл

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Мечтаю вынести стринговые переменные в отдельный файл, потом вызывать их по мере необходимости. Как то так:

strings.js

```
var hello = "Здравствуйте, ";
var h_are_you = "Как поживаете?";
```

index.html

```
<div>
 <script>
  alert(strings.hello + strings.h_are_you);
 </script>
</div>
```

Но не тут то было... Как "договориться" с браузером?

Comment: "string.hello" - подумайте, к чему Вы тут обращаетесь?

Comment: Если Вы о моей опечатке string  вместо strings , то я её исправил. Но должен сообщить, что этой ошибки нет в моём исходном коде. Отвечая на Ваш вопрос. Я обращаюсь к переменной hello из класса(?) файла(?) strings.js

Comment: @CoffeJava Декларирование переменных в отдельном файле не создает для них отдельного пространства имен.

Comment: Поправьте меня пожалуйста если я ошибаюсь. Для корректной работы моего кода я должен объявить стринги в head сайта? Я верно интерпретировал Ваш комментарий?

Comment: @CoffeJava - это Вы к кому обращаетесь?

Comment: @Igor Я обращался  к Вам

Comment: @CoffeJava из моего комментария Ваш вывод не следует

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56068/discussion-between-coffejava-and-igor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете, конечно, убрать `strings.` из Вашего алерта, и все будет работать, если файл `strings.js` включен в страницу до вызова `alert`:

```
alert(hello + h_are_you);
```

Но, чтобы не засорять глобальную область видимости отдельными переменными, сделайте их свойствами объекта:

strings.js

```
var MyStrings = {
  hello: "Здравствуйте, ",
  h_are_you: "Как поживаете?"
}
```

index.html

```
<div>
 <script>
  alert(MyStrings.hello + MyStrings.h_are_you);
 </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<script>
  var strings = {
    hello: "Здравствуйте, ",
    h_are_you: "Как поживаете?"
  };
</script>

<script>
  console.log(strings.hello + strings.h_are_you);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

В одном фале напишите:

```
var string = {
hello : "Здравствуйте, ",
h_are_you : "Как поживаете?"
}
```

и подключите его до исполняемого файла, а также почитайте про requireJS